# SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want move a project from a host to my host.
but after the moving and change the .env file and config/database.php file, appeared this error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'test_root'@'mailserver63.mylittledatacenter.com' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from `orders` where `status` not in (CANCELLED, COMPLETED) and `api_order_id` is not null order by RAND() limit 15)

this is config/database codes:

```
<?php

return [

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| PDO Fetch Style
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| By default, database results will be returned as instances of the PHP
| stdClass object; however, you may desire to retrieve records in an
| array format for simplicity. Here you can tweak the fetch style.
|
*/

'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_OBJ,

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Default Database Connection Name
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify which of the database connections below you wish
| to use as your default connection for all database work. Of course
| you may use many connections at once using the Database library.
|
*/

'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Database Connections
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here are each of the database connections setup for your application.
| Of course, examples of configuring each database platform that is
| supported by Laravel is shown below to make development simple.
|
|
| All database work in Laravel is done through the PHP PDO facilities
| so make sure you have the driver for your particular database of
| choice installed on your machine before you begin development.
|
*/

'connections' => [

    'sqlite' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlite',
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
        'prefix' => '',
    ],

    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'host' => 'mysite.com',
        'database' => 'test_root',
        'username' => 'test_root',
        'password' => 'rootpassword1234',
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
        'modes' => [
            'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES',
            'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE',
            'NO_ZERO_DATE',
            'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO',
            'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER',
            'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'
        ]
    ],

    'pgsql' => [
        'driver' => 'pgsql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'prefix' => '',
        'schema' => 'public',
        'sslmode' => 'prefer',
    ],

],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Migration Repository Table
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This table keeps track of all the migrations that have already run for
| your application. Using this information, we can determine which of
| the migrations on disk haven't actually been run in the database.
|
*/

'migrations' => 'migrations',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Redis Databases
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Redis is an open source, fast, and advanced key-value store that also
| provides a richer set of commands than a typical key-value systems
| such as APC or Memcached. Laravel makes it easy to dig right in.
|
*/

'redis' => [

    'cluster' => false,

    'default' => [
        'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
        'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
        'database' => 0,
    ],

],

'installed' => '1',
'transfer_mode' => '%transfer_mode%',
];
```

I don't know what the connection with `mailserver63.mylittledatacenter.com` is and where is this phrase in my project.
I even used a tool to find mylittledatacenter phrase in my project files. Among my project files, I did not find any file software that came with that term.

Comment: Can you run `php artisan config:clear` and try again?

Comment: No, I don't have access to cmd

Comment: this project is in my hosting

Answer (score 0):

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=database_name
DB_USERNAME=username
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

Three Steps to resolve this error or set the database in Laravel:

1. First add the database name (`DB_DATABASE=database_name`) in project `.env` file.
2. Then add the username of database (`DB_USERNAME=username`) in project `.env` file.
3. then add the password of the database (`DB_PASSWORD=password`) in project `.env` file.

Resolved this error following above steps SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user in Laravel

Comment: install all dependency of laravel project